# Spring and angular5 XSRF security issue

Tags: spring, angular

i have project where i using spring as backend (generated with microservices with jhipster) and angular5 as frontend

on server side setup CSRF security is added(it was by default enable when we create microservices with Jhipster)

as i work with angular , there is no need to make changes in angular code for dealing with XSRF token sending(csrf and XSRF are same things)

question background :

when i test both UI and apis locally it works great.in this case 
server will setup cookies as XSRF-TOKEN on browser cache and angular app return this cookie in header for each request. this works fine at locally

angular app at local : http://localhost:4200

api gateway app local  http://localhost:8080

question :
when i deploy this app on dedicated server

angular app at : http://111.22.33.44/angualrapp

api gateway at : http://111.22.33.44:8080

(above are the assumed domain , same pattern used for my apps)

when i did this setup i have facing following problem
- XSRF token is not getting stored at my browser cache
- each request gives me 403 Forbidden error (because ,i thought XSRF-TOEKN is null)

Q 1 . how did i get solved above problem ?

Q 2 . Is this configuration is possible when Angular and Spring code is deployed to different domains(origins)?

Q 3 . can i facing this problem due to domains i allocated to apps ?

Answer (score 0):

hello friends i just go through deep in this issue , i get help from the following issue

[Share cookie between subdomain and domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookie-between-subdomain-and-domain/23086139#23086139)

Q 2 . Is this configuration is possible when Angular and Spring code is deployed to different domains(origins)?

ans : need to host both apps on same parent domain
for example:

angular app : angularapp.parentdomain.com

api's :       apis.parentdomain.com:8080